Automatically generate a comment when you vote to close a post
Except when you vote to close a question as a duplicate of another, this doesn't seem to happen.
So, it would be great if, when you vote to close a post, a comment was automatically generated with the reason. Some users just don't know that their post is not suitable or off-topic, even if you vote to close the question. When you comment on their posts, they will get notified, though. So, that's why I always try to comment and explain why I vote to close a post, but this is time consuming. So, it would be great if there was a way to create pre-determined comments, which I can choose from, based on what I want to say.
This was probably already asked many times, but what's the status?

If you vote to close from a review queue, or if you flag the post, then an auto-comment is generated.

@Chenmunka Yes, thanks, I knew that, but it would be great if we could have something like that when we're reading the post normally and also have our own pre-defined comments.

Why don't you ask this on the main Meta site instead of here?
